# scrapy inline-requests doesn't work with async functions

Tags: python, scrapy, python-asyncio

My complete code:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
from typing import Any, Optional, cast
from inline_requests import inline_requests
from scrapy import Spider, Request
import asyncio
    
class QuotesSpider(Spider):
    name = "scraper"

    custom_settings = {
        "TWISTED_REACTOR": "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor",
        'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter',
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        codes= ["A", "B"]
        url = "https://somesite.com/"
        for i, code in enumerate(codes):
            yield Request(url=url, callback=self.handle, meta={'cookiejar': i, "code": code})

    @inline_requests
    async def handle(self, response):
        code = response.meta["code"]
        cookiejar_ref = response.meta["cookiejar"]

        # Parse csrfToken from the html
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
        relevant_script = [script.text for script in soup.find_all("script") if "csrfToken" in script.text]
        matched_group = re.search(r'"csrfToken":"(.+?)"', relevant_script[0]) if len(relevant_script) > 0 else None
        if matched_group is None:
            raise Exception("Failed to extract csrfToken")
        csrf_token = matched_group.group(1)

        await asyncio.sleep(1) # <-- Need async because of this (and for more async related tasks after wards like calling websocket, etc)
       
        # Initiate search
        api = "https://somesite.com/search"
        headers = { "x-csrf-token": csrf_token, 'Content-Type':'application/json' }
        payload = {"a": 1}
        response = yield Request(api, method='POST', headers=headers, meta={'cookiejar': cookiejar_ref}, body=json.dumps(payload))
        lots_url = json.loads(response.text)["redirect"]

 
        yield {
            "lots_url": lots_url,
        }
```

The issue is here (adding async keyword causes the function not to wait anymore):

> async def handle(self, response: Response):

Don't want to do it the callback way as the code was becoming unreadble (there are lots of other functions that i have omitted here for breivety). Only way i found to call scrapy requests sequentially was to use [scrapy-requets-inline](https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-inline-requests) but it stops working as soon as i add the async keyword on the function definition. Remove that and it works as expected (i.e waits for request to finish before proceeding further). Any way to make it wait with the async keyword?.

One alternative i know is to ditch scrapy entirely and use aiohttp but doing that will mean losing all the awesome features that scrapy provides (like rate limiting, logginh stats via scrapymd etc).

Thanks!

Comment: Putting async in front of a method definition changes the method from an ordinary one into a coroutine function.  Calling the method does not cause it to run, instead it returns a value that is a coroutine object.  Coroutines must be scheduled as tasks or executed in an await expression.  The problem is not that scrapy doesn't work any more, it's that you are apparently trying to use coroutines without creating the whole asyncio apparatus.  You don't necessarily need to discard scrapy but you need to restructure your program as an asyncio-based application.

Comment: Any idea how i would do that?  scrapy requests take in a callback and if it were javascript, i would just wrap the whole thing in a promise and resolve it inside the callback. But I am having a hard time implementing that approach in scrapy